# Get the google plus URL based on place_id of Google Places API?

Tags: google-places-api

How can I get the plus.google URL page of the corresponding google place based on the place_id I obtain from the json the maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place returns?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use the Place Details api using the place_id?

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

Comment: The API no longer supports this. It now only returns http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=...

Answer (score -1):

This seems old post now but wanted to add some more details. 'places' details API provides google plus URL:

Quoting from https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details:

> **url** contains the URL of the official Google page for this place. This will be the establishment's Google+ page if the Google+ page exists,

You once you have place_id, use:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=your_key&placeid=interested_place_id

And look for 'url' key.

Its a different question if  you want to extract details from that page. I do not know if google has API for this.