# Get a google plus URL based on place_id or other location data as input

Tags: google-plus, google-places-api

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25571372/1168364) is no longer correct - the url returned is now always a maps.google.com url. Is there a way to get the google plus url from either the place id or with some other programmatic means?

- I'm okay with using an API that costs money.
- I'm okay with using some
  other location information as input but would prefer to use place id
  as input.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: No, I wasn't able to.